# Error: Hybris Plugin Validation. How to resolve it?

Tags: intellij-idea, sap-commerce-cloud

Error: Hybris Plugin Validation

When I try to run junit test I got this error.

Comment: [Disable/uninstall](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html) the Hybris plug-in?

Comment: Maybe try to refresh your workspace? File / Refresh Project